# data_post_url from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to call a controller everytime I change the date. In this example the BirthdateCHanged Action inside the Order controller.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Birthdate, "DateRow", new { @data_request_url = Url.Action("BirthdateChanged", "Order"), @minDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-115), @maxDate = DateTime.Now, @defaultDate = DateTime.Now, @viewMode = "years", @readonly = "true", @class = "form-control" })
```

DateRow View looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group @(Html.IsValid(m => m) ? "has-success" : "has-error")">
@Html.ActiveLabelFor(m => m, new { @class = @ViewData["labelClass"] })
<div id="divReload" class="@ViewData["inputGroupClass"]" data-provide="datepicker">
    <div id="divReload" class="input-group">
        <input type="text"
                 value="@displayDate"
                 name="@Html.IdFor(m=>m)"
                 class="form-control ajaxSubmitOnChange"
                 data-date-language="@Culture.ToString()"
                 data-date-picktime="false"
                 data-date-mindate="@ViewData["minDate"]"
                 data-date-maxdate="@ViewData["maxDate"]"
                 data-date-defaultdate="@ViewData["defaultDate"]"
                 data-date-viewmode="@ViewData["viewMode"]"
                 readonly="@ViewData["readonly"]"
                 data-post-url="@ViewData["data_post_url"]"
                 @(Html.IsRequired(m => m) ? "data-val=true" : "") />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible, or I should search for other scripts?

**EDIT** I tried with the changeDate event as  Dante Xe suggested, but I don't know how to do it properly:

```
$(document).on('changeDate', '.datepicker', function (event) {
debug_log('document.change(.datepicker)');

url = $(this).data('post-url');
url += (-1 == url.indexOf('?') ? '?' : '&') + 'ajax=1&autosubmit=1';

$.post(
     url,
     $(this).data('post-params') != null ? jQuery.parseJSON($(this).data('post-params')) : $(this).serialize(),
     function (data) {
        postDispatch(data);
     }
);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

in date select, is fired event changeDate
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate

Comment: how to call it from the view?

Comment: $("#datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {
    //your code
});

Comment: I edited my question. I don't know how to invoke that event properly